# join two tables on argument1 ends with argument2

Tags: sql, sql-server

TABLE_A contains an `NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL` column `Name`. Its fields are made up of company names followed by an underscore and ending in a company id, e.g.:

> MYCOMPANY_102

TABLE_B's PK is an `INT NOT NULL` column called `CompanyID` and would contain e.g. `102`

My query, to inner join these two tables where one argument ends with the other, yields no results. In case anyone wonders the obvious: yes, there are matching records.

```
SELECT * FROM [SERVER1].[DB1].[dbo].[TABLE_A] a
INNER JOIN [SERVER2].[DB2].[dbo].[TABLE_B] b
ON a.Name LIKE '%[_]' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, b.CompanyID)
```

Any corrections and insight into why my query can not work, is most welcome.

**EDIT:** company names can contain digits and/or underscores anywhere, I'm ONLY looking to lock on to a possibly last occurrence of an underscore, followed by an arbitrary natural int. Could be _1, could be _205952 for all I know. There are NO leading zeros in the digits  suffix

Comment: Why not `LIKE '%_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, b.CompanyID)`? I don't understand the use of `[]` (although I have never done a like on a join :) )

Comment: the underscore is literal, not a wildcard

Comment: without the square brackets, the underscore is a one-char wildcard, the percent sign is a multi-char wildcard. That wouldn't work. I implemented the underscore myself to allow for company names that might, of and by themselves, end in digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is take that ID out from the name and join on it like here.

```
SELECT * FROM [SERVER1].[dbo].[TABLE_A] a
INNER JOIN [SERVER2].[dbo].[TABLE_B] b
cast(right(a.NAME, len(a.NAME)-charindex('_',A.NAME)) as int) = b.CompanyID
```

Comment: hmmm... "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'MYCOMPANY' to data type int."

Comment: Then maybe the data is not consistent, as in always Companyname_Number.

Maybe there are data looking like this "The_Biggest_Company_999"?

Comment: That's possible. I'm only looking for a final underscore, followed by an arbitrary natural int.

Comment: If that is the case, just use this one instead.

SELECT * FROM company A
INNER JOIN zip b
ON cast(reverse(left(reverse(A.name), charindex('_',reverse(A.name))-1)) as int) = B.CompanyID

Comment: clever, but still not quite right. "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: That can only be because some of the names have no _number

Comment: I had forgotten to filter out only the records that HAVE an underscore with a `WHERE` clause. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your problem is trailing blanks on the company name.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) points out:

> LIKE supports ASCII pattern matching and Unicode pattern matching.
>   When all arguments (match_expression, pattern, and escape_character,
>   if present) are ASCII character data types, ASCII pattern matching is
>   performed. If any one of the arguments are of Unicode data type, all
>   arguments are converted to Unicode and Unicode pattern matching is
>   performed. When you use Unicode data (nchar or nvarchar data types)
>   with LIKE, trailing blanks are significant; however, for non-Unicode
>   data, trailing blanks are not significant. Unicode LIKE is compatible
>   with the ISO standard. ASCII LIKE is compatible with earlier versions
>   of SQL Server.

This is just a possibility.  As a note, when you use `varchar` or `nvarchar` in a `convert()`, you should *always* include the length.  This is not affecting you here.

I think you are better off with this comparison:

```
cast(SUBSTRING(a.name, charindex('_', a.name)+1, LEN(a.name)) as int) = b.CompanyId
```

By using an equi-join on `CompanyId`, you have the opportunity to use indexes on that column.

Comment: on a side note: the values are always trimmed of leading and trailing spaces prior to insert

Comment: @WimOmbelets . . . Could you have leading 0s in the number?

Comment: `LEN(a.Name)` should be `LEN(a.Name) - CHARINDEX('_', a.Name)`

Comment: @WimOmbelets . . . Your calcualtion of length is techically more accurate.  However, if the length parameter is larger than the length of the string, it will just take the characters to the end of the string, so accuracy doesn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: I see. I've learned quite a bit reading all these answers since SQL is not my forte. Thanks for your input in any case. The issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
Like '%[_]' +  Cast(b.CompanyID as Varchar(100))
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13223)

Comment: no joy, I've got company names that end in digits. I'm getting results but the wrong ones.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this might help:

```
SELECT * FROM [SERVER1].[dbo].[TABLE_A] a
INNER JOIN [SERVER2].[dbo].[TABLE_B] b
ON a.Name LIKE N'%[_]' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, b.CompanyID)
```

I've tested your code and its working perfectly for me. The only reason that could be is that there are no matching records.

Answer (score 0):

Something may not be as you believe, since most of the code on this page (including yours) should work, or at least return *something*.

I would recommend selecting these tables into local temp tables (allowing you to inspect data types/lengths), running `ltrim(rtrim(...))` even if you think you don't need to, using `N` to mark literals as unicode, explicitly setting the width of your strings, etc. Anything that can increase simplicity or safety could help you find the problem.

Hair-pullers often end as head-slappers.

```
SELECT Name INTO #TABLE_A FROM [SERVER1].[dbo].[TABLE_A];

SELECT CompanyID INTO #TABLE_B FROM [SERVER1].[dbo].[TABLE_B];

-- Now you can check to see that the columns above are what you believe,
-- and then run your select or any of the selects that have been offered.

SELECT a.Name, b.CompanyID
FROM #TABLE_A AS a
    INNER JOIN #TABLE_B AS b
        ON LTRIM(RTRIM(a.Name)) LIKE N'%[_]' + CAST(b.CompanyID AS NVARCHAR(11))
```

Also, `[SERVER1].[dbo].[TABLE_A]` looks odd for [4-part naming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx). Do you mean `[DB1].[dbo].[TABLE_A]` or `[SERVER1].[DB1].[dbo].[TABLE_A]` instead?